# dropzone.js BEFORE file added event

Tags: dropzone.js

I need to know how to access an event BEFORE adding file preview (not addedfile event because it's actually called after adding file, so does accept event)
I need something like this

```
    myDropzone.on("beforeaddedfile", function(file) {
      if(/*some condition*/)
    //add file
    else
   // don't add file


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be able to do almost the same thing with "addedfile" event, like this:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  if(/*some condition*/) {
    //continue to do something and add file
  } else {
    // don't add file 
    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
  }
});
```

I hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an (currently) undocumented event named `addedfiles` which gets `files` as a parameter, which will trigger before the event `addedfile`:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfiles", function(files) {
    if(/*some condition*/){
        // add files
    } else{
        // don't add files
    }
});
```

Found in the source code: https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/blob/master/src/dropzone.js#L114

This helped me getting the total number of added files before `addedfile` is called.

But note that this is only called once, when adding files to dropzone.